# Ubuntu 10.04 external monitor problem

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, resolution, ubuntu-10.04, nvidia-settings

I've just installed the 10.04 release on my laptop. I've also installed the nvidia propietary driver as suggested by the system. I've some problem using an external monitor, i'm not able to set the correct resolution using the nvidia-setting utiloty. It doesn't recognize the right resolution of my external monitor. Any advice please? :) I'm a newbie.

Comment: Comment by suwa: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The xserver would recognize the native resolution of some monitors but not others.  (I found this problem when I bought a new monitor it wouldn't recognize)  It is important to note LCD's have a native resolution.  Some can scale it to other settings, but the best is to use the native one. (CRT's on the other hand have a wide range  of available resolutions)

Try this thread.  It did the trick for me.  In the first instruction when you are listing available resolution modes, do you see the native one for your monitor?  Most likely not, and that is why it doesn't let you set it.  Follow the instructions there, and it should work after.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html